# Is LINQ always preferred before sorting in an SQL-statement?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

We need to retrieve a sorted list of items. The sort order is to be related to an arbitrary list of items' guids. I.e. it might be *1, 2, 3, 4* as well as *3, 7, 2, 4*.

We're not using LINQ-to-SQL nor stored procedures.

I suggested that we fetch the list in the order SQL Server provides it and sort it using LINQ in the C# code.

The alternative to that is to create a string like this (following [this tip](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/17288)).

```
select * from publishers
Order by (CASE City
 WHEN 'Paris'    THEN 1
 WHEN 'Chicago'  THEN 2
 WHEN 'Boston'   THEN 3
 WHEN 'New York' THEN 4
 ELSE 100 END) ASC, City DESC
```

I must admit that there's a certain neatness to this approach but I really prefer to play with data operations in C#. I can't come up with a good shoot-down to the other approach, so I'll have to admit that it's a working one.

What are the drawbacks here? (Except for the obvious of injections, of course, which isnät a problem for us. We need not to worry about security issues, luckily.)

Comment: It largely depends on one question: are you *paging* the data, or are you fetching it all? If you are *paging* it, you have little choice except to sort at the server. If you are fetching it all, it frankly doesn't matter where you sort it - and it may indeed be more scaleable to sort at the application tier (you typically have more app-servers than database-servers)

Comment: @MarcGravell Fetching all at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally go for database centric solution. If I need sort or page a data, I almost always try to do it on DB server side (usually using `SQL` and/or `StoredProcedures`).

Benefits are evident:

1. Server is *usually* is the most powerful machine in the your app system, so let's give the hard work to it. Also because it's tuned to do the hard work for us.
2. One time data prepared on the server, sometimes it means that it also reduced its size too (filtered or fetched concrete page), so the data amount transmitted to the client is drastically reduced, which benefit to a user in faster response time.

If you're fetching all at once (as you mentioned), *at least*, the first point remain something that you can consider.

Comment: Out of interest what makes you think the data is being requested from the SQL server from a client?

Comment: I don't mean Microsoft SQL Server, but some SQL database(just loooking on the sample code you presented in question)

Comment: I don't but the "most powerful machine" argument; the db server might be powerful, but it is a pinch point. Anything you can do to **remove** load from that server is a good thing. Your app servers are far more outwards-scaleable. My point is: "give the hard work to the least scaleable part of your system" is not necessarily a great idea.

Comment: @MarcGravell: OP's is aksing about "rough" sorting, fetching or whatever. So, in case when the data is completely fetched (always), having client machine do all hard work, is not necessary a good option too. This is a thin decisional layer in architecture that is hard to give a "nailed" answer on, so what remains is a "general rule", the rest is bounded to concrete user context.